# Woher der Name "Reinecke Fuchs"?

Tags: etymology

Reinecke Fuchs ist eine Fabelgestalt die auf altertümlichen Stoff zurückgeht. Ihm verdankt z.B. der Bezirk Reinickendorf (Berlin) sein Wappentier. Der Name existiert auch niederländisch als *Reynke de Vos*,
*Van den vos Reynaerde*, mittelhochdeutsch *Reinhart Fuchs*, und französisch im *Roman de Renart*. Dementsprechend ist Reinecke eine niederdeutsche Form von René, so viel scheint klar zu sein. Das Wesentliche steht bei Wikipedia.

Warum aber hat das Tier diesen Beinamen erhalten?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Laut Wikipedia gibt es neben Reineke, der Fuchs; auch Isegrim, der Wolf; Braun, der Bär; und Hinz, der Kater. Für mich scheint es einfach nur ein Name zu sein? Weiterhin: "Die heute gebräuchliche Namensform Reineke Fuchs wurde zuletzt durch das gleichnamige Versepos Johann Wolfgang von Goethes etabliert."

Comment: @infinitezero Ich gebe keine Methode vor, das musst du dir selbst erarbeiten. Im Grunde gibt es nix zu verstehen. Angenommen ein Nutzer erhält den Namen infinitezero, klingt das Praefixes erstmal negativ und die Null am Ende macht außer für Informatiker auch keinen Sinn. Man könnte natürlich wie bei *infero* ein ursprüngliches *\*dh* vermuten, was auch zutrifft, und mit Verhärtung durch *\*-s* Endung ("Wie heth. *ḫa-an-za* / hant-s/ ‚Vorderseite,
Stirn‘ zeigt", ewa.saw-leipzig.de: “enti", vgl. “endi”) *endlos* vergleichen, was weniger negativ wäre, um gekonnt die Theorie in Frage zu stellen.

Comment: @infinitezero: Goethe hat vermutlich mit eine Rolle gespielt und das ist sicher *ein Teil* der Antwort. Auf der anderen Seite hat er sicher auf Bestehendem aufgebaut bzw. aus älteren Quellen geschöpft und ich verstehe die Frage so, daß es gilt, diese älteren Quellen zu benennen. Ich könnte mir vorstellen, daß die "Initialzündung" der Namensgebung onomatopoietisch war, ähnlich wie das etwa Karl Kraus mit seinem ungarischen "Géza von Lakkati de Némesfalva et Kutjafelegfaluszég" in den "Letzten Tagen der Menschheit" gemacht hat.

Comment: Über den er in einer Bemerkung sagte: "die schwer auszusprechen sind, aber leicht den ganzen Ekel der Epoche vermitteln“ (Fackel 521, S161), und weiter, daß der Name nicht zufällig oder leichtfertig erfunden wurde, sondern einer ist, "den ich, reiflicher als Franz Josef I. den Weltkrieg, erwogen habe" (ibid)

Comment: @bakunin Ich glaube nicht, dass sich der gute Goethe auch nur den geringsten Gedanken über den Vornamen vom Fuchs gemacht hat: Er hat ihn einfach so gelassen, wie er schon seit dem elften Jahrhundert überliefert war.

Comment: @tofro: Ich habe meine Zweifel bei allen Begründungen, die mit "ich glaube [nicht]" beginnen. Es gab auch mal eine ganze Menge Leute, die nicht glaubten, daß die Erde was anderes als eine Scheibe sei. Daß Goethe sich sehr wohl Gedanken um die Benamung seiner Figuren gemacht hat, erhellt etwa die Quelle, die ich verlinkt habe, beim "Mittler" aus den Wahlverwandtschaften. Ich jedenfalls glaube nicht, daß der gute Goethe sich anderswo weniger Gedanken gemacht hat.

Comment: @Bakunin Dein letzter Satz hat mich (in Kombination mit dem ersten) sehr gefreut ;) Übrigens: Goethe hat auch den Eckart, den Egmont, die Iphigenie, den Torquato, den Götz und den Faust genau so gelassen, wie er sie vorgefunden hat.

Comment: @tofro: Grade bei Goethe bin ich mir ziemlich sicher, daß er über die Namen seiner Figuren sehr genau nachgedacht hat. Im Zuge seiner Auseinandersetzung mit den Klassikern (insbesondere Klopstock) sagt Klopstock über ihn: "Der von den Göttern du stammst, von Goten - oder vom Kothe.", worauf Goethe meint, der Name sei "kein Kleid, an dem man unbedacht zupfen und zerren" dürfe.

Comment: @bakunin ... wahrscheinlich hat er deshalb an Reinekes Namen nicht "unbedacht gezerrt und gezupft", sondern ihn ganz einfach gelassen, wie er war.

Comment: Das mag sein oder auch nicht - was genau sich Goethe gedacht hat, wird sich nicht eruieren lassen. Aber eigentlich lautete die Frage ja nicht, wie Goethe auf diesen Namen gekommen ist, sondern, weshalb der Name überhaupt so ist wie er ist - eben "Reinecke" oder eine Abwandlung davon und nicht "Hans", "Kurt", "Willy" oder sonstwie.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist ganz einfach ein Name, übernommen aus der originalen "Reineke"-Geschichte. Schon in der ersten überlieferten (in Latein geschriebenen) "Fuchs-Löwe-Bär"-Geschichte aus dem elften Jahrhundert hieß der Fuchs *Reinardus*, also ähnlich. Die Namen vieler anderer Figuren aus der Fabel (Isegrim, Braun, Lampe und Grimbart - für Wolf, Bär, Hase und Dachs) lassen schon lange vor Goethe in europäischen Tierfabeln nachweisen.

Dass der Vorname aus dem Germanischen übersetzt soviel wie "schlauer Ratgeber" bedeutet, hat wahrscheinlich auch damit zu tun, dass er als Name für den Fuchs geeignet erschien, da dem Fuchs schon immer Intelligenz und Fintenreichtum zugeschrieben wurde.

Comment: Woher kommt dann der Name aus der "originalen Reinecke-Geschichte" - die vermutlich nicht zu verifizieren ist, dazu ist das Sagen- und Fabelmaterial zu vielfältig und die primäre Quelle zu weit entfernt. Außerdem ist - siehe meine Antwort - die Übersetzung eben nicht "schlauer Ratgeber", sondern "-hart"="kühn, stark".

Comment: Die erste (bekannte) "Reinardus"-Geschichte stammt aus dem elften Jahrhundert. Ob es noch primärer geht, weiß keiner, bis einer was älteres findet. "hart" bedeutet tatsächlich hart, kühn und stark, aber auch scharf und spitz - Beides ein Ausdruck für "schlau". Nicht alles, was richtig ist, ist die alleinige Wahrheit.

Comment: Daß "hart, stark, kühn, scharf und spitz" Ausdrücke für "schlau" sind, ist diskutabel, aber darauf wollte ich gar nicht hinaus. Auch nicht darauf, von wann die erste "Reinardus"-Geschichte stammt (meines Wissens gab es da Vorläufer bis ins Altertum - Aesop, Phaedrus, etc.). Die Frage ist, so habe ich es verstanden, warum der Fuchs gerade "Reinecke" oder ähnlich heißt - und eben nicht "Hans", "Kurt" oder sonstwie.

Answer (score 1):

Anstatt einer Antwort, oder: Versuch einer Themenverfehlung

Es könnte sein, daß sich die Frage nach der speziellen Figur "Reinecke der Fuchs", bzw. der Herkunft seines Namens nicht restlos aufklären läßt. Die bereits genannten Hinweise auf Goethe, Gottsched bzw. niederdeutsche Versepen ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reineke_Fuchs)) sind vermutlich nicht mehr als das - Hinweise, die auf noch ältere, aber nicht greifbare Quellen verweisen. Im Folgenden werden deshalb einige Methoden der Namensgebung abgehandelt, die aber vermutlich - wenigstens in "Reinform" - nicht als Erklärung für die Genese von "Reinecke" herangezogen werden können. Wahrscheinlich liegt eine Mischung aller dieser Möglichkeiten am Anfang der Entwicklung, die mit "Reinecke Fuchs" (wengistens vorläufig) endete.

Eine in der genannten Quelle angeführte Deutung des Namens (neben "Reinecke" auch "Reinardus", "Renart" "Reinhart", ...) aus "regin-" (Rat) und "-hart" (stark, kühn) ist sicher nicht von der Hand zu weisen, obwohl seit Äsops und Phaedrus' Zeiten der (Fabel-) Fuchs weniger für Stärke und Kühnheit als vielmehr für Listigkeit und flexible Moral (bis hin zur Verschlagenheit) steht. Ihm entspricht nicht der Achilles, sondern eher der Odysseus.

Generell gibt es eine Reihe von Mechanismen, die zur Namensgebung herangezogen werden können:

**Onomatopoiesis**
Wenn ein (etwas ungeschickter) Kobold "[Pittiplatsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pittiplatsch_und_Schnatterinchen)" heißt, dann hat das mit dem Geräusch des Fallens, wenn wieder einmal einer seiner Pläne mißlingt (was ziemlich oft der Fall ist), zu tun. Onomatopoiesis beschränkt sich aber nicht nur auf solche einfachen Geräuschnachahmungen. Eine andere Art von Lautmalerei stellt etwa Karl Kraus' ungarischer Hauptmann *Géza von Lakkati de Némesfalva et Kutjafelegfaluszég* aus "Die Letzten Tage der Menschheit" dar, von dem der Autor (Fackel 521-530, S161) sagt:

> [Er] führt, wie dies gar nicht anders möglich ist, den Namen Géza von Lakkati de Némesfalva et Kutjafelegfaluszég: einen Namen, den ich, reiflicher als Franz Josef I. den Weltkrieg, erwogen habe, indem ich einen Kenner von Honvédmöglichkeiten bat, mir eine Reihe solcher Komposita vorzuschlagen, die schwer auszusprechen sind, aber leicht den ganzen Ekel der Epoche vermitteln [...]
> <sub>[Die Fackel online](https://fackel.oeaw.ac.at/)</sub>

**Sprechende Namen**
Manche Namen werden so gewählt, daß sie etwas über die Funktion der Figur im entsprechenden Text etwas aussagen. Typisch sind etwa der "Legionär Taubenus" aus den Asterix-Comics, aber auch etwa der "Mittler" aus Goethes "Wahlverwandtschaften" (zur Analyse dieser Figur siehe [hier](http://www.goethezeitportal.de/db/wiss/goethe/wahlverwandtschaften_hildmann.pdf)), der eine - wenn auch ambivalente - vermittelnde Funktion erfüllt.

Andererseits heißt der "Erzengel Michael" nach dem Schild mit der Aufschrift "Min ka El" ("Wer [ist] wie Gott?"), den er in der Schlacht trägt. Die Aufschrift bedeutet im Wesentlichen, daß sich niemand mit Gott vergleichen kann, es also sinnlos ist, sich gegen seine Auswerwählten zum Kampf zu stellen.

**Konnotierende Namen**
Namen können aufgrund von Assoziationen, die sie auslösen, verwendet werden. "Meier" etwa ist ein sehr häufiger Name und es liegt nahe, ihn mit Alltäglichkeit bzw. Durchschnittlichkeit zu assoziieren. Folgerichtig benennt Konstantin Wecker den Helden seines Liedes "[Laufen Sie doch mal Amok](https://wecker.de/portfolio-item/laufen-sie-doch-mal-amok)" "Meier":

> Er hieß Meier und sah eigentlich genauso aus,
> und er wollte mal so gerne aus dem Meierdasein raus. ...

Dieser Text wäre nicht möglich (bzw. würde seine Wirkung verfehlen), wenn nicht sichergestellt wäre, daß das Publikum mit dem Namen "Meier" dasselbe assoziiert wie der Sänger - in diesem Falle die Durchschnittlichkeit, die mit dem Namen verbunden wird. In dieselbe Kategorie fällt auch der "Karl-Heinz Jürgen" aus "Junge, wir können so heiß sein" von Extrabreit.

**"Typische" Namen**
Bestimmte Namen können auf Eigenschaften der benannten Figur hindeuten, indem sie für diese Eigenschaft "typisch" sind. Letztlich ist dies - wie andere, bereits erwähnte Namengebungsmethoden - ein Spiel mit verbreiteten Vorurteilen und oft genug tragen Vertreter einer bestimmten Eigenschaft andere als "typische" Namen. Die Frage aber ist nicht, wie "realistisch" diese Erwartungen sind, sondern, ob sie zwischen Autor und Leser so verbindlich sind, daß sie als Transportvehikel einer bestimmten Botschaft taugen.

Eine Figur namens "Mordechai Weizenkajm" hat wohl eine andere Abstammung als ein "Andrzej Kowalski" und wenn die Berufe "Bergbauer" und "Matrose" zur Auswahl stehen, welchem davon geht wohl "Piet Henning" nach und welchem "Pankratius Hintergstöttner"?

**Die Dialektik der Namensgebung**
Nicht nur werden Bedeutungen durch die Namensgebung transportiert - umgekehrt wird durch die Benutzung der bedeutungstragenden Namen die Assoziation der Bedeutung mit dem jeweiligen Namen bzw. Namenstypus verstärkt. Wenn in einem Witz eine Person namens "MacGyver" vorkommt, dann ist sie geschickt und handwerklich begabt - und jedesmal, wenn das passiert, dann wird diese Assoziation "MacGyver = geschickt" fester und selbstverständlicher. Das hat nichts mit dem Namen "MacGyver" an sich zu tun - hätte die Figur in der Fernsehserie, die an Anfang dieser Entwicklung stand, stattdessen "Johnson" geheißen, dann hätten wir jetzt bei diesem Namen dieselbe Assoziation.

Comment: In *Pitti* ist ohne weiteres französisch *pétit* "klein" erkennbar. Zudem geht *Peti* landläufig als form von *Peter* bzw. *Petra* durch, dessen griechische Herkunft wohl zweifelhaft ist. Gehört hier aber njcht rein. Sonst müsste man auch den *Loki* vergleichen. Hey, warte mal, worauf läuft das hinaus ...

Comment: Zweitens hieß altdeutsch *michel* ungefähr "groß", was sicherlich zur Verbreitung des Namens *Michael* beigetragen hat. Dieses namenprägende Grundmuster der Addaption (nicht "Assoziation") fehlt in der Antwort und geht somit an der Frage vorbei. Denn wo *regin* "Rat" angesetzt wird, könnte noch mehr dahinterstehen.

Comment: *Adaption*, nicht "addaption" m)

Comment: @vectory: Ich dachte eigentlich, das im Abschnitt "Sprechende Namen" abgehandelt zu haben. Wenn "Michel" "groß" heißt, dann ist das doch sprechend, oder? Natürlich kann ich den Stoff hier nicht erschöpfend behandeln - "Namensgebung und Namensnennung in der deutschen Literatur" wäre ein Dissertations- wenn nicht Habilitationsthema - deshalb sind manche Feinheiten hier unberücksichtigt geblieben.

Comment: Ja, Karl "Der Große" wäre sprechend. Satzgefüge mit "El", "Ya" usw. sind aber die Regel für Namen des betreffenden Sprachraums. *Sprechendes Wappen* ist z.B. das von Berlin (nicht Bär-lin). Da ist denkbar, das Schild Michaels sei ein solches gewesen, vielleicht mit Hieroglyphen (Eliš ist aber akkadisch, Elam ein Königreich flussaufwärts). Darum ging es hier nicht, da Bezug zum Reinhard fehlt. Sprechend wäre es, wenn der Titel z.B. als Sammlung von Er-zählungen aus dem Rhein-Gebiet galt (vgl. engl. *art* "Kunst" < *ars* ~ *artem* "skill", auch "cunning"; de. *Art* "genre", engl. *order* usw.)

Answer (score -2):

Warum heißt der Bösewicht aus Star Wars "Darth Vader"? Warum heißt der Kerl, der Goliat erschlagen haben soll ausgerechnet "David"? Und warum heißt der erschlagene Riese "Goliat"? Warum heiße ich "Hubert"?

Die Antwort ist immer dieselbe: Jemand hat für diese Personen aus schwer nachvollziehbaren Gründen, die meist nur dem Namensgeber allein bekannt sind, eben genau diesen Namen gewählt. Das hat in manchen Fällen damit zu tun, dass der vergebene Name eine bestimmte Bedeutung hat, viel öfter aber nicht. Und das machen auch die Urheber von Fabeln genau so. Irgendjemand hat aus irgendeinem nicht mehr nachvollziehbaren Grund befunden, dass "Reinecke" (oder eine ältere Form dieses Namens) gut als Name eines fabelhaften Fuchses geeignet ist, und hat mit diesem Namen eben einen Fuchs bezeichnet. Die Zuhörer fanden das nicht sonderlich unpassend, und akzeptierten den Namen und erzählten die Fabel mit diesem Namen weiter, und so verbreitete sich dieser Name. Viel mehr wird da nicht dahinterstecken.

<sub>Ein Beispiel: Mein Vorname "Hubert" bedeutet "der mit dem hellen Verstand" oder "der mit dem glänzenden Geist" (*hug* = Geist, Verstand; *bert* = hell, glänzend). Aber bekommen habe ich diesen Namen nicht wegen dieser Bedeutung (die kannten meine Eltern gar nicht), sondern, weil sich meine Eltern bei einem Tanzkurs in einem Landgasthof mit dem Namen "Hubertushof" kennengelernt haben. Der Gasthof, in dem viele Wildgerichte angeboten wurden, ist wiederum nach dem heiligen Hubertus, dem Schutzpatron der Jäger benannt. Diese Schutzfunktion wird dem heiligen Hubertus von Lüttich zugeschrieben, weil dieser beim Jagen ein Kruzifix im Geweih eines Hirschen gesehen hat und dadurch sehr religiös wurde. Aber warum dieser Hubertus von Lüttich ausgerechnet "Hubertus" und nicht etwa "Bernhard" oder "Ulrich" hießt, weiß auch wieder niemand.</sub>

Comment: Siehe meine Bemerkung unter der Frage. Über den Gebrauch von Namen und die Art, Namen zu erfinden, die eine bestimmte Art von Bedeuetung transportieren, sind schon meterweise Bücher geschrieben worden. Wenn Konstantin Wecker in "Laufen Sie doch mal Amok" so eröffnet: "Er hieß Meier und er sah auch ganz genauso aus" - dann bedeutet das, daß "Meier" offenbar für eine Art von Aussehen steht, die von Publikum und Sänger verstanden wird. Da einfach herzugehen und "schwer nachvollziehbar" zu behaupten, greift ein wenig zu kurz.

Comment: Die Antwprt geht an der Frage vorbei. Die Fabel hat eine jntensive Forscbungsgeschichte. Daher hoffe ich, irgendwer hätte mal einen sinnvollen Ansatz entwickelt.